# Android how to detect call logs programatically

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am trying to read call logs and save to an external storage. I have used

```
 cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"),    projection, selection, selectionArgs,sortOrder);
```

By this method I am successfully reading and saving all call logs to external storage. Now if a new call is received or made or call is missed then how can I track it and save it to my storage without saving all calls that are being read from cursor. I know broadcast receiver or service will be best in this case but unable to figure it out that how can I made it to work. Any working example or code snippet will be rally helpful.